# Possible to use something like setRequestedOrientation for one View only?

Tags: android

I am having two Views in one Activity, a background in the bottom View and some control elements in the top View. I would like to lock the orientation for the bottom View so it doesn't rotate when the device is rotated but the control elements should still be changing/rotating.

I know this is possible on the iPad. Is there an equivalent for Android? Or is it possible to have two Activities overlapping each other where the top Activity is transparent apart from the control elements? And would the bottom Activity receive any touch events in that case?

Comment: Yes it possible to have two activities overlapping each other and the top activity could be transparent. I suggest you to go through APIDemos example for the solution. There is example based on this.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I am now using two activities with the top activity being transparent but this activity now catches all touch and click events and none are going to the activity below. Is there a way to pass them through?

Comment: I managed to pass the events through with an invisible layout underlying the top activity but when I lock the orientation of the bottom activity, the top activity is also locked. Can I explicitly set it to not be locked?